# How can I make Grease Pencil solid fill a mesh's intersection with camera?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I'm trying do what is similar to an architectural section where everything is rendered normally but the meshes that clip through the active camera have their areas rendered as a solid color fill. Something like this, where the meshes being cut are filled solid black:[image]

I've been trying to accomplish this with the Grease Pencil Line Art Modifier to no avail. There's always some issue with the way Blender is processing the geometry for what seems like a simple task.

The object I'm trying to do this on:[image]
The result I'm currently getting: [image]
What the result should look like: [image]